# Programmatically restarting the Web Service on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, service

In Xcode on Lion I'm attempting to manage the Web Service programatically. Simply, I want to be able to start, restart and stop the service from via my own buttons.

I suspect that the System Preferences or perhaps even the Sharing Preferences offer some kind of functionality to do so?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you taking about "Web Sharing", i.e. the apache web server? You can certainly control it in the System Preferences. However, if you want to control it programmatically, you can use `apachectl` just like on any unix server. So, for example

```
apachectl start
apachectl stop
apachectl restart
```

Comment: When I mention the System Preferences, I know that I can do it via the GUI, but I'd guess normally any type of Preference package might make various functions available to other applications. Like "Preferences.Sharing.RestartWebService()".

My point is that I'd really like to do this the most "Mac"-way possible.